# Integration tests, unit tests and code coverage

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

I was reviewing some code for a colleague and came across a test in the unit test class that looked this:

```
// setup
Foo f = ...
FooToBarConverter ftb = ...
Bar b = ftb.Convert(f); // It is easier to create a Bar by converting it from a Foo than making one 'from scratch'

// test
systemUnderTest.DoSomething(bar);

// assert
Assert.IsTrue(...)
```

Clearly this is an integration test as it is testing the FooToBarConverter as well as the system under test as it is the only test that covers the DoSomething() method. I suggested moving this test to an integration test solution, however this reduces the code coverage of the unit tests. We are aiming for 100% unit test code coverage (and yes - I know that 100% coverage is a means to an end not the end itself, and 100% covered code is not necessarily 100% correct code).

Is there a reason for creating unit tests to bring the coverage back up if we move the integration test out?

Or are we aiming for the wrong thing with 100% unit test coverage? Should we be aiming for 100% coverage with the combination all our tests (or even aiming for 100% at all)?

Thank you.

EDIT/UPDATE:

This is not a question about how to unit test the system under test properly (I know the reasons that this is not a unit test, and I know how to properly convert it into a unit test), nor is it a question on coverage on FooToBarConverter. I want opinions on code coverage on the system under test: are integration tests on the system under test sufficient? or should there also be unit tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer here is "it depends".

- If you have full unit test coverage on the `FooToBarConverter` class then probably you are OK just with the integration test of `systemUnderTest` because you can say with confidence that the real `FooToBarConverter` behaves as expected in this context and therefore does not incorrectly influence the result of the test.
- On the other hand, it's unclear specifically what this test is checking for - are you examining the behaviour of `systemUnderTest` when given a valid `FooToBarConverter`, or some other expected side effect within `systemUnderTest` to which `FooToBarConverter` is a purely coincidental actor? (i.e are you sure that this isn't an indirect test of `bar`?)

Now *personally* I would recommend that you also do a proper, "pure" unit test (using a mock or stub of `FooToBarConverter`) for `systemUnderTest` because

- it will make regressions easier to manage; suppose that in the future some change to `FooToBarConverter` makes its unit tests fail - they will quite possibly also therefore make this integration test fail. That could be confusing for someone looking at failed tests and not knowing that the integration test failure can be ignored and that only the FooToBarConverter tests need to be fixed. It's a small thing, I know, but it might save 5 important minutes some day :)
- How do you test the negative cases (behaviour of `systemUnderTest` when given a broken/invalid/null `FooToBarConverter`)? Since you'll probably have to write unit tests with stubs/mocks for these kind of cases anyway, you might as well have a unit test for the good case in the same project/test class as well, it's much clearer - otherwise you have to aggregate code coverage across both unit test and integration test projects to verify that `systemUnderTest` is fully covered...

Also, don't worry about 100% code coverage; it's nice to have but in practice it's rare to see it. I don't mean this as a sop to good design practices either; the simple reality is that no design is 100% perfect and therefore it's to be expected that there are times when you just don't have the time/resource/will to refactor your classes to allow every single dependency to be injected, or to be able to use interfaces for every inter-seam interaction, etc.

Hope that helps.